# \hl gives 5 errors and I don't know why

Tags: color, soul

The sentence

```
\hl{Upphängningsmetoden visade att masscentrumet låg i punkten (10,5;7,30) i centimeter medan den algebraiska metoden visade på att tyngdpunkten låg i $(10,5;7,34)$}
```

gives 5 errors and I don't know how to fix it. Here is a sample of the doc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel} 
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\section*{Sammanfattning}
Denna rapport kommer att undersöka masscentrumet hos en pappersfigur med två metoder - en algebraisk och en experimentbetonad metod. Därefter ställs dessa metoder mot varandra och jämförs. \\
Den algebraiska metoden utfördes genom att rita in figuren i första kvadranten i ett koordinatsystem och figuren var mätt i SI-enheten centimeter. Sedan användes bland annat arean för två områden i figuren samt beräknades tyngdpunkten för dessa områden för att sedan kunna utreda hela figurens masscentrum. Den experimentbetonade metoden utfördes genom att hänga figurskivan i tre punkter, dra tre lodlinjer från desssa punkter och bestämma masscentrum genom konstruktion. Båda metoderna gav givande resultat då båda fick samma tyngdpunkt men den algebraiska metoden var mest effektiv. \\
Resultatet besvarade alla tre frågeställningar som ställdes i rapporten och innehållet följde syftet.\hl{Upphängningsmetoden visade att masscentrumet låg i punkten (10,5;7,30) i centimeter medan den algebraiska metoden visade på att tyngdpunkten låg i $(10,5;7,34)$}. Skillnaden mellan dessa metoders resultat är knappast stor men den algebraiska metoden ses som mest trovärdig på grund av att metoden hade en högre noggranhet än upphängningsmetoden. Upphängningsmetoden hade vissa brister men det påverkade knappast resultatet. Dock kan det påverka andra mer komplicerade föremål där upphängningsmetoden kan vara svår att genomföra med.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the package `soulutf8` instead of `soul`. I tested your sample with the package replaced, and it works ...